# Fetching the list of all files within a repository specific to a commit id by using GitHub APIs

Tags: git, github, github-api

I am trying to see, if GitHub API's are available to see contents of repository at a specific commit id level.

Example:
I am able to see an output from the below endpoint, where output is provided in JSON.
But, this output if from master/main and shows content from the last commit.

Repo URL = https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes

URL: https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kubernetes/git/trees/master?recursive=1

Output: Reduced content

```
{
  "sha": "4916b6cd7486e2e0dd6ce5417ae4e6842356954a",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kubernetes/git/trees/4916b6cd7486e2e0dd6ce5417ae4e6842356954a",
  "tree": [
    {
      "path": ".generated_files",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "4e417ab3d2552386cf373e7d41dbdedd7dc5854c",
      "size": 766,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kubernetes/git/blobs/4e417ab3d2552386cf373e7d41dbdedd7dc5854c"
    },
    {
      "path": ".gitattributes",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "022e4cde51e5618685b8c946df693c2f04a23fcb",
      "size": 381,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kubernetes/git/blobs/022e4cde51e5618685b8c946df693c2f04a23fcb"
    },
```

Question is - How can retrieve a similar output for a specific commit id by using GitHub APIs?

Example: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/4916b6cd7486e2e0dd6ce5417ae4e6842356954a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by replacing the branch name (`master`) with the commit id.

https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kubernetes/git/trees/4916b6cd7486e2e0dd6ce5417ae4e6842356954a?recursive=1

Additionally if you want information about the commit, you can replace `trees` with `commits`.

https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kubernetes/git/commits/4916b6cd7486e2e0dd6ce5417ae4e6842356954a?recursive=1

Comment: The Otterlord - Thanks a lot for this answer! It really saved sometime for me.